# Где начался деепричастный оборот? Быть запятой или не быть?

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

> Тут уж я приказным тоном ему в спину: стойте, говорю, немедленно
>   стойте! Он остановился, но даже не обернулся. Я подошла и эротично ему
>   шепчу: «Скажите прямо сейчас: вы любите дельфинов?» **Он обернулся и
>   так спокойно глядя мне в глаза,** отвечает: «Я люблю деньги». И всё.
>   Дальше пошёл.

*Он обернулся и (ЗАПЯТАЯ?) так спокойно глядя мне в глаза, отвечает...*

Или:

*Он обернулся и так спокойно (ЗАПЯТАЯ?) глядя мне в глаза, отвечает...*

Или ещё что?

Comment: Почему в первом предложении нет прямой речи (в отличие от других)?

Comment: А это не дословно - пересказан (автором) смысл свой попытки остановить негодяя.

Comment: Слово "говорю" и весь строй этого предложения мешает мне воспринимать написанное как пересказ.

Comment: А Вы хотите *Тут уж я приказным тоном ему в спину: "Стойте, - говорю, - немедленно стойте!"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он обернулся и так спокойно, **глядя мне в глаза**, отвечает...

Такая структура предложения выглядит более естественной, а слишком тонкие смысловые оттенки с помощью одной пунктуации вряд ли воспринимаются.

Comment: А пожалуй, вы правы! Если автор хочет выразить что-то иное, то нужно не запятые переставлять, а слова менять.

Answer (score 1):

*Он обернулся и, **так спокойно глядя мне в глаза**, отвечает...*
Такая пунктуация подходит, если в предыдущем тексте был намек на беспокойство, неуверенность (или другие чувства) **в глазах** мужчины.

***Он обернулся и так спокойно***, глядя мне в глаза, **отвечает**...
Такая — если беспокойство или неуверенность (или что-то другое) были **в его голосе**.

[Помню, что авторский текст надо холить и лелеять, но: совсем рядом находятся два глагола "обернулся". Возможно, один из них стоит заменить на "оглянулся"?]

**Дополнение**

*...я союз "и" ощущаю (здесь) не как обернулся и отвечает, а как и так спокойно глядя в глаза... Этим вызван вопрос.*

Для того, чтобы обозначить резкость движения, можно использовать тире и убрать "отвечает":
**Он обернулся — и так спокойно, глядя мне в глаза: «Я люблю деньги».**

Comment: "Обернулся" обыграно: вот не оборачивался, не оборачивался и - хоп! -  обернулся!

Comment: Римма, я союз "и" ощущаю (здесь) не как *обернулся и отвечает*, а как ***и так спокойно глядя в глаза***... Этим вызван вопрос.

Comment: Я тоже "ощущаю", что он спокойно глядел ей  в глаза, а автор хотела подчеркнуть, что герой говорил о деньгах **не смущаясь**

Comment: Тут надо прочувствовать ситуацию: спокойно смотрел в глаза — не видел в происходящем ничего особенного. Говорил спокойно, глядя в глаза — сохранял спокойствие в необычной ситуации, а возможно, хотел что-то подчеркнуть этим взглядом.